# How can I draw the 3d blood vessel

Tags: 3d

[image]

How can I draw the 3d blood vessel as the picture showing?

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried so far? Can you show us code? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: LaTeX and its drawing-related tools are not the best way to produce such images. If you have the image you can _insert_ it in the document loading the package `graphicx` and then calling `\includegraphics[<options>]{<picture_name>}`. Please have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). @Downvoters: is it really necessary to downvote (twice!, so far) the first question of a new user?

Comment: @downvoters: please be patient with this first post. Minus one is more than enough after 26 minutes of waiting for an MWE. Thanks.

Comment: To @George. You can create a 3D red blood cell using Blender. A curve with a couple of tangente constraints, a revolve and voilà. Copy and rotate it and you have the other RBC. The blood vessel is a cylinder with a texture. Pick a camera and render everything in a png image. If it seems like a lot of work is because it is. And none of it is related with LaTeX...

Comment: While I disagree with voting below -1, this question does need improvement as it is not a reasonable one as asked. So I don't think it should be up-voted beyond -1 - 0 at most - either.

Comment: @cfr: I did not vote in any direction but I think this question is off-topic since almost impossible to produce an image like above even with TikZ, so it's not an TeX - question at all

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I agree. But since it is a first question, I thought it might turn into a more reasonable one if it turns out the OP is interested in including the picture or something. But, as asked, it is not reasonable. (I don't say it is impossible just in case!)

Comment: @cfr: stickler to the rules: I said 'almost impossible'... but I believe that external tools like Blender etc. might do this job better than a LaTeX approach.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was trying to agree with you ;).